# The column from which to return VLOOKUP responses depends upon the value of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

With Cell `F1` a drop down menu, I'm trying to look up the value of `A2` on sheet 2 and if `F1` contains:

- "Test1 1/2", then return the data in the 3rd column
- "Test1 2/1", then return the data in the 4th column
- "Test2 1/2", then return the data in the 5th column
- "Test2 2/1", then return the data in the 6th column.

I was able to figure it out using a total of four `if` functions, except the equation shows "wrong number of arguments to IF":

```
=IF(F1="Test1 1/2",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,3,false),
 IF(F1="Test1 2/1",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,4,false)),
 IF(F1="Test2 1/2",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,5,false)),
 IF(F1="Test2 2/1",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,6,false)))
```

Comment: Please share a doc with us and show us the expected outcome. `VLOOKUP` is the correct direction, but shifting them into columns is another thing.

Comment: I went ahead and figured it out on my own. Trial and error, with some searching.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question? That perfectly normal here on Web Applications. We might learn from it !!

Comment: I've prepared an example file for you, to show you how the `VLOOKUP` formula works: http://goo.gl/nfP6K

Answer (score 2):

According to OP (who seems unlikely to post an answer as such):

`Here is the correct equation`:

```
=IF(F1="Test1 1/2",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,3,false),IF(F1="Test1 2/1",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,4,false),IF(F1="Test2 1/2",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,5,false),IF(F1="Test2 2/1",vlookup(A2,Sheet11!A2:F,6,false)))))
```